# iOS - How to attach a JSON Object to web request? (NOT using NSURLConnection)

Tags: ios, json, web-services, nsdata, nsurlrequest

I am trying to send some web requests to back-end API I have setup on my web server.
However, to make things universal I would like to send an entire JSON object to the back-end, and do all my filtering of data there to determine what the request is for, what arguments to pass, etc.

I will be making many requests from one class to different services, so I don't want to use NSURLConnection as it gets messy having to filter through all the results in the completion handler to determine which request was originally being fetched.

I like how NSURLConnection allows you to attach a JSON object like this, but I want to know how to do it with a different method (say [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:])

```
NSMutableDictionary *postObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[postObject setValue:@"login" forKey:@"request"];
[postObject setValue:inputUsername.text forKey:@"userName"];
[postObject setValue:inputPassword.text forKey:@"password"];

NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postObject options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"WEB_URL"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setTimeoutInterval:20];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: not an answer, but.. why don't you use RestKit? - https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit  it makes work with services easier.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is to make a NSObject class with a NSURLConnection in it and set a Property Tag on the class. Then you have the NSObject/NSURLConnection class with the connection return itself to the delegate when the download finishes. You have a method like the -(void)downloadFinished example below to handle the reply in the delegate.

In the NSObject Class you use NSJsonSerialization to convert the NSDictionary to Json and append it to the NSURLConnection.

I wish I could link you to the JsonHelper Class on Github however I have not uploaded it to Github yet :(.

Example Request:

```
NSDictionary *post = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Json_Value",@"Json_Key",nil];

JsonHelper *jsonHelper = [[JsonHelper alloc]initWithURL:@"http://mycoolwebservice.com" withDictionary:post
withMethod:@"POST" showIndicator:NO withDelegate:self withCache:NO];
[jsonHelper setTag:1];
[jsonHelper connectionStart];
```

Delegate Reply Example:

```
-(void)downloadFinished:(id)sender
{
   if ([sender isKindOfClass:[JsonHelper class]]) {

    NSError *error = nil;
    JsonHelper *jsonHelper = (JsonHelper*)sender;
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:jsonHelper.receivedData];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    

    if (jsonHelper.tag == 0) {

    // Do Something
    }

    else if (jsonHelper.tag == 1) {

    // Do Something Else
    }
  }    
}
```

It should not be too difficult to write your own custom class to do more or less the same thing using this example.

Comment: Yeah that defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do though. I could just use NSURLConnection and it's delegate for completion handling. I want to keep the entire process inside it's own method to try and keep things organized and easy to follow.

Comment: If you want to keep it contained then Blocks seem the logical choice. This might help you out: http://blog.logichigh.com/2010/09/12/cocoa-blocks/

Comment: And Another: http://messagesenttodeallocatedinstance.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/nsurlconnection-with-blocks/

Comment: Yes, I ended up using the NSURLConnection's sendAsynchronousRequest to create a block and process the data within there. Still might be messy due to having to use notifications to then proceed to the next step, but at least I don't have to keep adding 'tags' or filters in my response data from the backend to determine what data is being received.